# Msg 207, level 16, STATE 1, Ligne 1 invalid column name 'TRF3110WJS'

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've created a trigger that changes a status of object (laptop, PC, printer, ...) to booked after update.

The script is in dynamic sql (the environment is SQL Server 2008 R2):

```
DECLARE @CMDB_ID int, @variable varchar(128), @CI_TYPE_ID int, @STATUS varchar(128),
        @mrSTATUS varchar(128), @stock_status varchar(128), @SERIAL_NUMBER varchar(128)

SET @CMDB_ID = 2
SET @stock_status = 'En stock'
SET @mrSTATUS = 'APPROUVEE'
SET @STATUS ='RESERVE'

Declare @sql nvarchar(max), @CRLF varchar(2)

SET @CRLF = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'Create trigger [dbo].[CHANGEMENT_ETAT_CI_EN RESERVATION]' + @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'ON [dbo].[MASTER4]'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'AFTER UPDATE'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'AS' + @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'if UPDATE(RECHERCHE__bNOUVEAU__bSERIAL__bNUMBER)' + @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'BEGIN' + @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET NOCOUNT ON;' + @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'  ' + @CRLF

SET @SQL = @SQL + N' DECLARE @CMDB_ID int,@variable varchar(128), @CI_TYPE_ID int, @STATUS varchar(128),@mrSTATUS varchar(128), @stock_status varchar(128), @SERIAL_NUMBER varchar(128)' + @CRLF

SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @CMDB_ID =' + CAST(@CMDB_ID as varchar(8))+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @status = ''' + CAST(@STATUS as varchar(128))+ '''' + @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @STOCK_STATUS = ''' + CAST(@STOCK_STATUS as varchar(128))+ '''' + @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @mrstatus = ''' + CAST(@mrstatus as varchar(128))+ '''' + @CRLF
SET @sql = @sql + N'  ' + @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'DECLARE c1 cursor for' + @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SELECT RECHERCHE__bNOUVEAU__bSERIAL__bNUMBER'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'FROM inserted'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'WHERE mrSTATUS = @mrSTATUS'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'open c1'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'FETCH NEXT FROM c1 INTO @SERIAL_NUMBER'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @variable =' + '(SELECT Num__UGLJ_ro__bde__bs__UGLJ_rie FROM [dbo].[CI&IN&STOCK] WHERE Num__UGLJ_ro__bde__bs__UGLJ_rie= @SERIAL_NUMBER)'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @CI_TYPE_ID =' + '(SELECT [dbo].[CI&IN&STOCK].CI_TYPE_ID FROM [dbo].[CI&IN&STOCK] WHERE Num__UGLJ_ro__bde__bs__UGLJ_rie= @SERIAL_NUMBER)'+ @CRLF

SET @SQL = @SQL + N'WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'BEGIN'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'Declare @sql nvarchar(max), @CRLF varchar(2)'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @sql=''''' + @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @CRLF = CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)' + @CRLF

SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @sql= @sql + N''update CMDB'' + CAST(@CMDB_ID as varchar(8)) + ''_CI_'' + CAST(@CI_TYPE_ID as varchar(8)) + @CRLF' + @CRLF

SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @sql= @sql + N''SET STATUS = '''''' + @STATUS + '''''''' + @CRLF' + @CRLF

SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @sql= @sql + N''WHERE Num__UGLJ_ro__bde__bs__UGLJ_rie ='' +  CAST(@variable as varchar(128)) + '' and STATUS = '''''' + @stock_status + '''''''' + @CRLF' +@CRLF

SET @SQL = @SQL + N'EXEC sp_executesql @sql'+ @CRLF    
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'fetch next from c1 into @SERIAL_NUMBER' + @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'END'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'close c1'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'DEALLOCATE c1'+ @CRLF
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'END'+ @CRLF

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

When I trigger this script throw an update of the MASTER4 table, the following error appears:

> Msg 207, level 16, STATUS 1, Line 1
>   Invalid name of column   : 'TRF3110WJS'

Even if the value 'TRF3110WJS' isn't a column name, it is a column value instead.

Any supporting idea?

NB: the script works well if I the name of the table is static instead of being dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the Dynamic SQL that creates more dynamic sql

```
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @sql= @sql + N''WHERE Num__UGLJ_ro__bde__bs__UGLJ_rie ='' +  CAST(@variable as varchar(128)) + '' and STATUS = '''''' + @stock_status + '''''''' + @CRLF' +@CRLF
```

You need more quotes around the

```
CAST(@variable as varchar(128))
```

bit.

I think this should do it

```
SET @SQL = @SQL + N'SET @sql= @sql + N''WHERE Num__UGLJ_ro__bde__bs__UGLJ_rie ='''''' +  CAST(@variable as varchar(128)) + '''''' and STATUS = '''''' + @stock_status + '''''''' + @CRLF' +@CRLF
```